# xamarin datepicker como configurarlo para solo digitacion

Tags: xamarin, xaml, mvvm, prism

¿Se puede convertir el control `datepicker` a un `entry` como es la versión de `wpf`?

Necesito que se digite la fecha, pero solo los números sin el separador, para que sea rápido de usar.

He intentado `xamarin.comunity.toolkit maskedbehaviour`, pero como uso `mvvm` el *behaviuor* no actualiza la propiedad asociada al control

Gracias

Comment: y usaste INotifyPropertyChanged para esa propiedad usando Binding?

Comment: claro, la propiedad esta  en un VM que implementa INotifyPropertyChange, uso PRISM, la propiedad es de tipo DateTime